# Can one find Variable Importance from a Random Forest model with mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, random-forest

I have been using Classify with Method-> "RandomForest", but I would like to know if I can get the variables importance. Is there a way to get this information  from the model?

Comment: Same question on StackExchange [importance of variables from classify](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102762/how-can-i-determine-the-importance-of-variables-from-classify)